# Nested variable creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-lists

I'm currently writing some code in python(3.6), and as I have quite a few variables with the same name (The only identifier is the ID of that variable.), I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like this:

```
for i in range(0.1):
        mapped_data{i} = 4
```

So like with strings and formatting hereof.

Or is the best way to do this, to create a (sometimes nested) list, with the size of how many variables I need of a particular variables?

Comment: Make `mapped_data` a dictionary and change the {curly braces} to [brackets]? Not sure what this "nested" thing is about. What determines if the list has to be nested or not?

Comment: Agree with @Aran-Fey, you would be best suited to use a dictionary with keys being your ID's and values being your associated variables

Answer (score 1):

Relying on numbered variable names is generally a bad practice. It pollutes your scope, making your code less maintainable and readable.

A sequence of values should typically be stored in a `list`. Note that since Python uses *lists* instead of *arrays* you do not have to worry about the size of that `list`.

```
mapped_data = []

for i in range(0, 10):
    mapped_data.append(4)

mapped_data[2] # 4
```

A group of labeled values which order does not matter should be stored in a `dict`.

```
mapped_data = {}

for name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    mapped_data[name] = 4

mapped_data['foo'] # 4
```